# Cant setup Elastic Search JAVA API

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have used elastic search in nodejs. But now for a java app I need elasticsearch. So I read the documentation in elastic search official website. But I cant follow one thing

I have installed Maven plugin in Eclipse. 
I have done dependency setup in pom.xml in my project.

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

But whenever I write below line in java it says cant resolve.

```
import static org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.*;
```

So I'm unable to use elastic search in java.

I have read this as source

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/index.html

http://java.dzone.com/articles/elasticsearch-java-api

Comment: Can you run a mvn clean install in debug mode and post the logs, its possible that your dependency is not resolved for some reason

Comment: @6ton Well I have installed maven in eclipse and created the project. I think eclipse will handle all dependencies

Comment: Its not magic :), try running a clean install and inspect the logs

Comment: I used mvn clean install. Build Success. But I cant see any file downloaded of elastic search. All downloads are of maven

Comment: Build succeeded - does that mean your code compiled with the above import?

Comment: No no. thats mean mvn clean install succeed. In elastic search the artifactid is given as elasticsearch but in this link there has not artifact id with only elasticsearch. http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22org.elasticsearch%22. Is it any problem?

Comment: The artifact is valid: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.elasticsearch%22%20AND%20a%3A%22elasticsearch%22

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have downloaded the jar file and added to build path. Let see if I can use it directly. +1

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are doing here, you shouldnt have to download the jar manually and add to eclipse as a project dependency. Please go through [this](http://stackabuse.com/maven-explained/) tutorial to understand how maven dependency works. Relevant text below:

> Maven connects to remote repositories (or you can set up your own
>   local repos) and automatically downloads all of the dependencies
>   needed to build your project. For example, lets say you have a project
>   that uses Apache's Camel routing tool, version 2.10.6, but a new
>   version of Camel is released, 2.11.1. Instead of having to go to
>   Apache's website, download the 2.11.1 distribution and replace 2.10.6
>   with it, you can just tell Maven to use the new distribution and the
>   work will be done for you.